# How to roll back everything except exception to store in the table

Tags: java, arrays, oracle, oop, java-8

I have asked related question earlier but didn't get answer, may be I didn't ask in right way. My question is, in my java program I want to roll back everything except the exception because when I roll back i want the user to know what was the exception caused, by storing it in table. Now am using session rollback,which is rolling back everything,even the exception stored in table, how can I avoid this tricky situation?

```
try {
initialSession.saveChanges();
response = BusinessObjectDispatcher.execute(request,BusinessObjectActionLookup.constants.ADD);
rootElement = response.getRootElement();
addError(CmMessageRepository.faCantbeCreated());
initialSession.commit();
} 
catch (Throwable e) {

initialSession.rollback();


}
return null;
```

Comment: Rollback..? Session rollback? Your question lacks sufficient information

Comment: can you add some example? I'm having problems understanding what are you asking...

Comment: I was using hibernate session roll back which is rolling back everything, i need to store the exception in table, but because of rolling back even the exception is stored also getting rolled back.

Comment: Please don't use comments to clarify you Q; update the body of your Q to clarify the description of your problem. Good luck.

Comment: Let the failed one roll back properly. Start a new transaction to save your exception. You also want to be careful with the exception handling of writing the exception because you don't want to trigger some infinite loop.

Comment: One way to do this would be to have stored procedure in pl/sql that is defined with 'pragma autonomous transaction' ( [link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/appdev.101/b10807/13_elems002.htm) ) that would insert your exception data to some table.
.
How to get it working with your particular framework - well i don't know :)

Answer (score 2):

Use a stored procedure to report the exception with the autonomous_transaction pragma.  That allows that procedure to run in its own transaction and commit outside the main rollback.  If you search the oracle documentation for autonomous_transaction you should find plenty of examples.  I've used this heavily for just this situation.

Answer (score 1):

As you said in comment you are using hibernate.
 I assume you are using "@Transactional" at service or dao level.

You can create new method/class also with  **@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)** this will not roll back in exceptin

```
public class AuditDao {
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public void log(Exception e){
    // ... save exception details as per requiremnet..
    // you can create some expection model and use it to insert or plain insert query
}
```

}

Call this method in your catch block.

```
try {
    initialSession.saveChanges();
  ....
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        initialSession.rollback();
        auditDao.log(e);
    }
    return null;
```

You can avoid initialSession.commit(); and  initialSession.rollback(); as hibernate @transaction annotation will take care of this